# changing the labels of JSON Grid

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I am using JSON Grid to display values with pagination.It shows page 1 and no records to display when no data in grid etc also for same jsp page i have to apply internationalization i.e i18N properties for chinease and spanish
So please let me know how to change the text page no, and No records to display to chinease and spanish 
I am using struts2-jquery plugin

Comment: How the title of your question is related to the content?

Answer (score 0):

@user1127176 you can use the head tag to set the local.

```
<sj:head locale="xx" ... />
```